# Errors only when code is iterated

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Hello I'm trying to have two for loops sweep two parameters and for each 2-tuple of those parameters I want to solve a differential equation.  To do this I have the following code:

```
range0=.1
range1=1

stepSize=.1  
timeMax=1000

dataHolder={{0,0,0}}

For [bigT=range0, bigT<=range1, bigT=bigT+stepSize,
For [tao=range0, tao<=range1, tao=tao+stepSize,
sol=NDSolve[{I*x'[t] == Exp[-((t-tao)/bigT)^2]*y[t], 
             I*y'[t] == Exp[-((t-tao)/bigT)^2]*x[t]+Exp[-((t+tao)/bigT)^2]*z[t],
              I*z'[t] == Exp[-((t+tao)/bigT)^2]*y[t], 
               x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0}, {x,y,z},{t,0,timeMax}]
S = Re[1 - (z[timeMax] /. sol)*Conjugate[z[timeMax] /. sol]]
dataHolder=Insert[dataHolder, {N[tao],N[bigT],N[S[[1]]]}, 1]
]
]
```

I wrote this by first testing:

```
sol=NDSolve[{I*x'[t] == Exp[-((t-tao)/bigT)^2]*y[t], I*y'[t] == Exp[-((t-tao)/bigT)^2]*x[t]+Exp[-((t+tao)/bigT)^2]*z[t], I*z'[t] == Exp[-((t+tao)/bigT)^2]*y[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0}, {x,y,z},{t,0,timeMax}]
```

this for various values of tao and bigT, with no error.  I also calculated S:

```
S = Re[1 - (z[timeMax] /. sol)*Conjugate[z[timeMax] /. sol]]
```

with no error and then even appended these results to dataHolder with no error.  I do this for multiple different values of tao and bigT with no error so I assume that this code is good to iterate, but when I do the for loops I get a bunch of errors.  All of the errors I understand I've fixed but the remaining ones seem cryptic.  Furthermore at the end of the loops dataHolder is still just {0,0,0} which is strange.  I would post the errors but they are sort of long, please let me know if I should do this.

Comment: looks like a job for `ParametricNDSolve`

Comment: Ah so the problem is that Mathematica has it's own function for this kind of thing?

Comment: So I've rewritten this such that I use ParametricNDSolve, but can you offer any reason why this code doesn't work?  I find the answer, "because there is already some other function for this task", kind of unsatisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing For and it's clutter with Table, you can do this easily:

```
timeMax = 1000;
Table[sol = 
  NDSolve[{I*x'[t] == Exp[-((t - tao)/bigT)^2]*y[t], 
    I*y'[t] == Exp[-((t - tao)/bigT)^2]*x[t] + Exp[-((t + tao)/bigT)^2]*z[t], 
    I*z'[t] == Exp[-((t + tao)/bigT)^2]*y[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, 
    z[0] == 0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, timeMax}]; 
    S = Re[1 - (z[timeMax] /. sol)*Conjugate[z[timeMax] /. sol]];
    {N[tao], N[bigT], N[S[[1]]]},
    {bigT, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {tao, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

One reason your For loop doesn't work is because you always Insert into the same position in the list.

Comment: Wow!  This is perfect and better than what I have made with ParametricNDSolve.  Thank you so much, if I could give you the reputation you deserve I would!

Comment: `Insert[…,1]` should be the same as `Prepend`.  Lack of semicolons is the main problem